# XSLT code for converting attributes to child elements and putting the value of current element into its another new child element

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am unaware of XSLT,Please help:
I have the following XML:

```
<OLifE>
  <Holding id="1234">
    <HoldingKey>1397650618090</HoldingKey>
    <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
    <HoldingStatus tc="2">Inactive</HoldingStatus>
    <CarrierAdminSystem>PAS</CarrierAdminSystem>
  </Holding>
</OLifE>
```

I want the output like this:

```
<OLifE>
  <Holding>
    <id>1234</id>
    <HoldingKey>1397650618090</HoldingKey>
    <HoldingTypeCode>
      <tc>2</tc>
      <value>Policy</value>
    </HoldingTypeCode>
    <HoldingStatus>
      <tc>2</tc>
      <value>Inactive</value>
    </HoldingStatus>
    <CarrierAdminSystem>PAS</CarrierAdminSystem>
   </Holding>
 </OLifE>
```

please note that, all attributes are needed to be converted to child elements but, for elements that have a `tc` attribute specified:

```
<HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
```

need to be handled carefully.

I DO NOT want the output like:

```
<HoldingTypeCode>
                <tc>2</tc>Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
```

I have the following XSLT code which needs the slight modification:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

 <xsl:output method="xml"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
       </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a *generic* solution, how about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- modified identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- attributes to elements -->
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- avoid mixed content -->
<xsl:template match="text()[../@*]">
    <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </value>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

> However, the root element in my original XML has got xmlns="some web
>   address" attribute.

In such case, change the first template to:

```
<!-- modified identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming you want all the output nodes to be in no namespace.

Comment: Thank you Michael! That solves the problem. However, the root element in my original XML has got xmlns="some web address"  attribute. In output I am getting xmlns attribute in every tag in the output XML file.

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary "*the root element in my original XML has got xmlns="some web address"*" Why is this not shown in your  question?!

Comment: Thanks for edit Michael, This was post hoc realization,triggered the miss

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a template like this to be called where you want to output the attributes :

```
<xsl:template name="transform.attrs">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

For the most general case you use almost the same template as before, just call the new template for attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:call-template name="transform.attrs">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And for the specific elements, bearing the `@tc` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@tc]">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:call-template name="transform.attrs" />
    <value>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </value>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi potame., The code is not working as expected. the transformation should take place based on specific attribute 'tc' which appears in different elements.

Comment: OK, this meant we were lacking a bit of information. I have updated my answer.